# Unclear step of logic proof

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I don't understand the bold line in the proof, I think it should be -2 because E' and E'' satisfies the condition 1. and 2. ,i.e. by E' we have -1 and by E'' we have another -1, so finally we have -2.However the proof says it's 1.

My definition of proper initial segment is

If and expression B can be written as CD where B$\neq C$, then C is called proper initial segment.

> Proposition: If we count each binary connective as 1, each propositional letter as -1 and negation as 0, then an expression B in Polish notation is a propositional formula if and only if:
>
> 1. The sum of the symbols is -1
> 2. The sum of any proper initial segment is nonnegative.

Proof:  ...\\fisrt part of proof (I understand it)...

Now consider E=KE'E'' a propositional formula, where E' and E'' are propositional formulas in polish notation with n or less connectives.

Suppose S is an initial segment of E, then we have 3 cases:

**1) If  S=K, then the sum of the symbols is 1.**

2)...

Comment: The sum of the symbols in the proper initial segment $K$ would indeed be 1, as $K$ is just a binary connective--unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: but in the line it doesn't just refers to S=K, it refers to the whole expression E=KE'E'' , Isn't it? @SpencerWhitehead

Comment: $E'$ and $E''$ are supposed to satisfy the inductive hypothesis.  Hence their sums are $-1$.  Together, they give $-2$.  Add $+1$ for $K$, and you get $-1$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi so is -1, a not 1. So the proof is wrong.ok

Comment: No, the sum of the symbols in $S$ is $1$.  It might have been states more clearly ("then the sum of *its* symbols is 1",) but it's obvious what's the intended meaning.

Comment: If $E=KE'E''$ is a formula in Polish notation, necessarily it starts with a conncetive. Thus, te symbol $K$ is a connective and its sum is $1$.